# Route Add Command, returns "Manipulates network routing tables."

Tags: windows, networking, routing, gpedit

Route Add Command, returns "Manipulates network routing tables." followed by the DOS route.exe help information.

Could gpedit.msc affect route.exe's ability to function, at one point I hardend the system and I think it might be affecting my ability to change the routing table.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank You.

Comment: By the sounds of it, you just got the syntax of the command wrong.
Could you show the `route add` command you tried to run?

Answer (score 0):

That is the normal output when you just type `route add`. It is expecting additional parameters (destination, gateway, netmask, metric, network interface..).